# Select where date is last week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a script that I want to pull all of the previous week's records. (7 days)

I have a date column and the data is stored in SQL Date format, like this: 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000 fore each row.

I want to select all rows where the date is the previous 7 days, not including the day that the query is ran on.

For example, if this query is ran on Monday it would include Monday - Sunday of the previous week, but not the current Monday when the query is ran.

This is where I'm at with the query but it doesn't work.

```
select f254,
       f01
from sal_reg
WHERE  F254 between(getdate() - 6 and getdate() -1;
```

F254 is field containing date time.

Comment: Prepare filtering arguments before query, then use them. Make them for example of `date` type to cut off time.

Comment: does you date include hours? if yes try cast(getdate() As Date)

Comment: Side note from SQL Server MVP Aaron Bertrand - [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Does the field `F254` ever include the time part?  Or is it ***always*** `00:00:00.00`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dateadd` for date arithmetic.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @MatBailie, since you say that `f254` is a `datetime` field, the safest thing is to use an upper bound that's one day past the end of the range that you want and then use `<` rather than `<=` on that side of the date range. This is because values stored in the `f254` column may have time components on them. Even if the software populating this database typically stores values in this field that have a midnight timestamp, it's not safe to assume that this will always be the case.

```
declare @Today date = getdate();
declare @LowerBound date = dateadd(day, -7, @Today);
declare @UpperBound date = dateadd(day, -1, @Today);

-- If f254 were a 'date' field, this would be appropriate:
select f254, f01 from sal_reg where f254 between @LowerBound and @UpperBound;

-- But if f254 is a datetime, then as @MatBailie points out, this is better:
select f254, f01 from sal_reg where f254 >= @LowerBound and f254 < @Today;
```

Comment: @MatBailie, I'm assigning `getdate()` to a local of type `date`, which should drop the time component from `getdate()`. I don't believe an explicit cast is necessary.

Comment: The Op doesn't specify, and hasn't responded to my comment, but it is *possible* that `F254` contains time parts as well *(the example demonstrates that it's a DATETIME field)*.  As that is the case, it would seems to be safer to use `>= @LowerBound AND < @Today`.

Comment: It seems like this should work but the query returns nothing. No errors.

Comment: Excellent point, @MatBailie. I've updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
  select f254,
           f01
    from sal_reg
    WHERE  F254 between DATEADD(day, -7, getdate()) and DATEADD(day, -1, getdate());
```

Comment: The question says that if the query is run on a Monday, the result set should begin with data from the previous Monday. So you want `-7` in your lower bound, not `-6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT f254
    ,f01
FROM sal_reg
WHERE CAST(F254 AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, - 7, CAST(getdate() AS DATE))
    AND CAST(F254 AS DATE) <= DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CAST(getdate() AS DATE));
```

Comment: The question says that if the query is run on a Monday, the result set should begin with data from the previous Monday. So you want `-7` in your lower bound, not `-6`.

Comment: you don't have to do anything with F254 since you're controlling right part of comparison

Comment: @JoeFarrell Thanks. Corrected

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks for the comment. I generally prefer to be explicit in these cases as it ensures that the predicate comparison is accurate even if there are future changes.

Comment: There is nothing to ensure about.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sal_reg where f245 >= DATE_ADD(current_timestamp, INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

As per the new format.

Answer (score -2):

```
select f254,
       f01
from sal_reg
WHERE  F254 between CAST(FLOOR(Cast(getdate() - 7 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) and CAST(FLOOR(CAST(getdate() -1 AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: that'd be suitable for 2000, not for 2008

Comment: it should work in SQL 2012 - in any case the SQL posted risks dropping records from the start of the same day as the day wears on, if the time stamp has time in it - I think the guy just had his -6 wrong though

Comment: there is `date` type in newer than 2000 versions.